# In meteor how to fix functionality for current instead of all?

Tags: html, meteor

In meteor I have created several new action cards from new action form. When I click on one action card the functionality is working for all cards instead of one card. How do I fix that problem. Can someone help me please.
Here I am attaching my code.
HTML:

```
        <!--New Actionform-->

 <div class="workflow" id="createAction">
   <form class="workflow-action-form" method="post" id="actionForm">
          <div> <input type="text" class="flow-title" name="action_title" placeholder="New Action Name" required/></div>

          <div class="form-line"></div>

       <fieldset class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="skills" name="description" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control m-b" name="team" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected">Enter or select Team or People</option>
                                   <div class="profile-img-header-no-image"><i class="pe-7s-user-female"></i></div>
                                    <option>Derek | Director</option>
                                    <option>Lisa | Producer</option>
                                    <option><i class="pe-7s-user-female"></i></option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="s_date" placeholder="Start Date" required/>
                 </div>
        </fieldset> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
       <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker4'>
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="d_date" placeholder="Due Date" required/>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
       </div>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control m-b" name="link" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Link to Meeting or Event</option>
                                    <option>option 1</option>
                                    <option>option 2</option>
                                    <option>option 3</option>
                                    <option>option 4</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
         <fieldset class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control m-b" name="module_list" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select a path to the module</option>
                                    <option> <a href="{{pathFor route='project'}}">
                                        <div class="nav-rec">
                                            <div class="icon-box one">

                                            <i class="pe pe-7s-display1 text-info"></i>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="module-name">
                                            <h5>Projects</h5>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a></option>
                                    <option>Collaborators</option>
                                    <option>Time</option>
                                    <option>Date</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="skills" name="notes" placeholder="Notes" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  <div class="flex-btn-force-right">

    <div class="btn-box">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cancelActionBtn">Cancel</button>&nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="createActionBtn">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>


</div>

<!---card after submission of new action form-->

<div id="newActionCard">
    {{#each newaction}}
                 <div class="workflowcard">
                 <div class="module-card">

                     <div class="  assigned-team">{{team}}</div>
                    <div class=" newaction-name">{{action_title}}</div><hr>
                    <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
                    <div class=" due-on">Due on:{{d_date}}</div><hr>
                    <div class="subcontent">
                  {{> actioncardsubcontent}} 
                 </div>
                 <div class="reqext">
               {{> requestextensioncard}} 
                 </div>
                   </div>
     <div class="btn-box newaction">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cancelsub">New Action</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="createbtnsub">Show Options</button>
    </div>
     <div class="btn-box showoption">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="hideoption" style="display:none">Hide Options</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="requestextension" style="display:none">Request Extension</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-box requestcard">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="cancelrequest" style="display:none">Cancel Request</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="submitrequest" style="display:none">Submit Request</button>
    </div>

            </div>

                {{/each}}
        </div>




</template>

<template name="actioncardsubcontent">
    <div class="subcontent">
             <div class="modulepath">{{module_list}}</div>
            <div class="linkto">Linked To: {{link}}</div>
             <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
     </div>


</template> 

<template name="requestextensioncard">
    <div class="reqext">
        <fieldset   class="form-group">
          <h4>Request Extension:</h4><br>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="skills" name="description" placeholder="Description" required style="height: 100px; width: 270px;"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control m-b" name="lengthOfExt" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected">Enter length of request </option>
                                    <option>One Day</option>
                                    <option>Two Days</option>
                                    <option>Three Days</option>
                                    <option>Four Days</option>
                                    <option>Five Days</option>
                                    <option>Six Days</option>
                                    <option>One Week</option>
                                    <option>two Weeks</option>
                                    <option>Three Weeks</option>
                                    <option>One Month</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
```

and JS:

```
Template.workflow.events({
    "submit .workflow-form": function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var workflowTitle = event.target.workflowTitle.value;
        var  project = event.target.project.value;
        var  description = event.target.description.value;
        var  team = event.target.team.value;
        var  s_date = event.target.s_date.value;
        var  d_date = event.target.d_date.value;
        var  link = event.target.link.value;


     var obj={
           workflowTitle : workflowTitle,
           project : project,
           description : description,
           team : team,
           s_date : s_date,
           d_date : d_date,
           link : link
        }; 
        event.target.workflowTitle.value="";
        event.target.project.value="";
        event.target.description.value="";
        event.target.team.value="";
        event.target.s_date.value="";
        event.target.d_date.value="";
        event.target.link.value="";

        $('#wfCard').show();
        $('#info').show();
        $('#createWF').hide();



 Meteor.call('insertWorkflow',obj);
      alert("submitted");

      },

      "submit .workflow-action-form": function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var action_title = event.target.action_title.value;
        var  description = event.target.description.value;
        var  team = event.target.team.value;
        var  s_date = event.target.s_date.value;
        var  d_date = event.target.d_date.value;
        var  link = event.target.link.value;
        var module_list = event.target.module_list.value;

     var obj={
           action_title : action_title,
           description : description,
           team : team,
           s_date : s_date,
           d_date : d_date,
           link : link,
           module_list : module_list
        }; 
        event.target.action_title.value="";
        event.target.description.value="";
        event.target.team.value="";
        event.target.s_date.value="";
        event.target.d_date.value="";
        event.target.link.value="";
        event.target.module_list.value="";

 Meteor.call('insertNewaction',obj);
      alert("submitted");

      },
});

Template.workflow.helpers({
    getWorkflow: function(){
        return Workflow.find();
    },
    user: function(){
 return  Meteor.users.find({});
 },
 getNewaction: function(){
        return Newaction.find();
    },

});

Template.wdashboard.onRendered(function(){

    // Initialize tooltips
    $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
        selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]"
    })

    // Initialize popover
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        trigger: 'focus'
    });

    // Initialize star rating
    $("#input-1").rating();

  // Hide Dashboard Button
   $('#info1').hide();
});

Template.workflow.events({
    "click .actionBtn":function(){

        $('#createAction').show();

    },
    //hide and show workflow buttons
    "click #createbtn" : function(){
        $('#editw').hide();
        $('#hidew').hide();
    },

    "click #createActionBtn" : function(){
         $('#editw').show();
        $('#hidew').show();
    },

   "click #createbtnsub" : function() {
      $( ".subcontent" ).show();

      $('.reqext').hide();
      $('#cancelsub').hide();
         $('#createbtnsub').hide();
         $('#hideoption').show();
         $('#requestextension').show();
       /* var id='#'+this._id; 
        $(id).show();*/
   },
   "click #hideoption": function(){
       $('.subcontent').hide();

   },

   "click #requestextension":function(){
      $('.subcontent').hide();
       $('.reqext').show();
       $('#cancelrequest').show();
       $('#submitrequest').show();
       $('#hideoption').hide();
       $('#requestextension').hide();
      },
      "click #cancelrequest":function(){
          $(".subcontent").show();
          $(".reqext").hide();
          $("#hideoption").show();
          $("#requestextension").show();
          $('#cancelrequest').hide();
          $('#submitrequest').hide();
      },

       "click #hideoption": function(){
         $(".subcontent").hide();
         $('#cancelsub').show();
         $('#createbtnsub').show();
         $('#requestextension').hide();
         $('#hideoption').hide();
         $('.reqext').hide();
     }, 


     "click #createbtn": function(){
         $("#editw").hide();
         $("#hidew").hide();
     },

     "click #createActionBtn": function(){

         $('#createAction').hide();
         $('#editw').show();
         $('#hidew').show();
     },
});

Template.actioncardsubcontent.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".subcontent").hide();
};

Template.requestextensioncard.rendered = function(){
    this.$(".reqext").hide();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you provided too much code, which make it hard to see the problematic part.  You should define your event handler:

```
Template.workflow.events({
     "submit .workflow-form": function(event, template) {
     }
});
```

Notice the second parameter.  Inside the event handler, you can use template.$('#wfCard') instead of just $('#wfCard').  The template.$ function limits the scope to the current template instance instead of search the whole DOM.  You should look at the generated HTML as well.  I think that you are not generating unique IDs.  For example, in the generated HTML, you cannot have two elements with the same ID.  You must somehow generate unique ID for each card or use another another CSS query.